# Gallery pop-up window, drupal 6

Tags: drupal

Hey guys, im really new to drupal but not PHP. 
I have a gallery where I would like a pop-up window option, so visitors can focus on images. (Lightbox is an alternative of course).

I've added an if statement in my page-node.tpl.php, which states if mode=biggallery then execute this code, if not, run page-node.tpl normally.

I achieve what I wanted but im unsure wether its allowed :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the Lightbox2 module, Modal API or something along those lines. It will keep you from having to inject code into the core tpl files.